# Can't get function to loop and pause using while True and time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

```
import time

while True:
    checksite()
    time.sleep(60)
```

I have written the code above as a part of a larger piece of code and can't get it to work. The project I'm working on is a web scraper that I want to run once a minute. checksite() alone works just fine.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting ? How is the above not working for you ?

Comment: I figured the answer out by myself. It had something to do with a twitter module I used. Thanks anyways!